# How to connect MySQL workbench with from shell using Python?

Tags: python, mysql-workbench

I have database in MySQL workbench and I'm running Python code from shell to connect to my database.

But I am unable to import mysql.connector or mysqlDb (got this suggestion from w3school). So I am unable to connect to my database.

Comment: Ya I'm using Python. `python`

Answer (score 0):

I think the question does not concern connecting with Putty, but more about importing mysql.connector in your python script.
**"But I am unable to import mysql.connector or mysqlDb ( got this suggestion form w3school)"**
--It will be easier to help you if your code is attached to your post.

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(########)
```

think this scrap of code will be helpful."Loading file from Oracle"

```
def load_file(DT):
ip = ######
port = #####
service_name = '#####'
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service_name=service_name)
t = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
SQL = "select name...."
fn = "/root/..." + t + ".csv"
fn_tmp = "/root/.." + t + ".csv"
FILE = open(fn_tmp, "w")
FILE.write(
    'name...;' + '\n')
out = csv.writer(FILE, delimiter=';')
logging.info("Database connect " + t)
try:
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('####', '###', dsn)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(SQL)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exc:
    conn = None
    error, = exc.args
    logging.error(
        "Oracle connection problem Error Code:{0}".format(str(error).decode("####",
                                                                            "ignore").encode("utf-8",
                                                                                             "ignore"))
    )
for row in cur:
    out.writerow(localize_floats(row))
logging.info("Database disconnect " + t)
try:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exc:
    error, = exc.argsgv[0]
    logging.error("Oracle-Error-Code:{0}".format(str(error).decode("####",
                                                                   "ignore").encode("utf-8",
                                                                                    "ignore"))
                  )
FILE.close()
os.rename(fn_tmp, fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option that you can try is to use pymysql. More info [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/). A code snippet is the following:

```
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host='IP',
                         port=3306,
                         user='user',
                         password='pass',                             
                         db='database',
                         charset='utf8mb4',
                         autocommit=True,
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    query = 'Your query'
    cursor.execute(query)

connection.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for Your Valuable answer but I am sorry I have done with my problem. and the que that  have asked was not proper as I was new to StackOverFlow.

Comment: Hi, do not worry. I am happy that you solve your problem. No need to be sorry about the question you asked. Properly asking and answering questions require practice and is important to start somewhere. Best Regards.